# Antd <DatePicker/> if value props is set, and click will be infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, antd

I want to set value in value props <DatePicker>. But if i set value, and if i click the date picker, calendar will be infinite loop to the future.
i have use DefaultValue and value props, but produce same error

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import type { DatePickerProps } from "antd";
import { DatePicker, Space } from "antd";
import moment from "moment";

const onChange: DatePickerProps["onChange"] = (date, dateString) => {
  console.log(date, dateString);
};
const day = moment();
const format = "DD.MM.YYYY";

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <Space direction="vertical">
    <DatePicker
      onChange={onChange}
      format={format}
      defaultValue={moment(day)}
    />
  </Space>
);

export default App;
```

You can try here
[SANBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-5-1-7-forked-p94zef?file=/demo.tsx)

and the picture is here
[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqehQ.png)

i have use DefaultValue and value props, but produce same error.
i have delete DefaultValue and value props and calendar is normal, but i cannot set value from beginning

Comment: antd v5 uses `dayjs`. Either you should use `dayjs` or if you want to use `moment`, create a custom datepicker that use moment [Use custom date library](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-custom-date-library#datepicker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation and the below error from the defaultValue when using moment js shows that the accepted format is day js

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Dayjs'.`

To resolve above issue of showing date , follow below steps

1. Import dayjs
2. Using defaultvalue attribute, assign current date using dayjs

```html
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import type { DatePickerProps } from "antd";
import { DatePicker, Space } from "antd";
//import moment from "moment";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

const onChange: DatePickerProps["onChange"] = (date, dateString) => {
  console.log(date, dateString);
};

const format = "DD.MM.YYYY";

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <Space direction="vertical">
    <DatePicker onChange={onChange} format={format} defaultValue={dayjs()} />
  </Space>
);

export default App;
```

Updated the codesandbox for your reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-5-1-7-forked-b87dbv?file=/demo.tsx

Documentation link for reference- https://ant.design/components/date-picker

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. I used day.js to solve that issue.
So use day.js instead of moment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35513757)